# Correlation failed for ASP.NET Core 6 MVC using OpenID and docker

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openid

I am using OpenID to connect to Keycloack and the ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application is running in a container, however I am getting correlation error after I successfuly login and logout the application or it is becoming intermittent like I can login to the app, then after few minutes and I open the same URL, I can no longer login, perhaps its the cookies missing or cant find or not matching.

I'm getting this error

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[15]
      '.AspNetCore.Correlation.XxYMZvzzXbtsXlUrwh1xD-uGyn24-skm69u0SIkk0LU' cookie not found.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HMP8EE71Q7FF", Request id "0HMP8EE71Q7FF:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
       ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

This is my `Program.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "oidc";
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Cookies";
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    // add an instance of the patched manager to the options:
    options.CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();

    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Authority = serverURL + "/realms/" + realm;
    options.ClientId = clientTd;
    options.ClientSecret = secret;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.ResponseMode = "query";
    options.UsePkce = false;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;

    options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = authorizationCtx =>
    {
        // access code thru authorizationCtx.TokenEndpointRequest.Code
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    };
    options.Events.OnTokenResponseReceived = ctx => {
        KeycloackAdapter.HandleToken(
            ctx.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken,
            ctx.TokenEndpointResponse.RefreshToken, 
            ctx.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken, 
            ctx.HttpContext
        );

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    };

    options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = userInfo =>
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    };
});

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Keycloak", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new KeycloakPolicyRequirement()));
});

services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, KeycloakPolicyHandler>();

services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
{
    // prevent JSON from changing to camelCase
    o.UseMemberCasing();
});

services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(
    new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "DataProtection"));

services.AddDataProtection().UseCryptographicAlgorithms(
    new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration
    {
        EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
        ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
    });

services.AddRazorPages().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

services.AddSession(options => {
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseHangfireDashboard();

app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None,
    Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
});

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
});

app.UseSession();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

I have tried every single possible solution i can find in stackoverflow or online to no avail.

Data protection is even set and since it is in docker, the volume is already mounted and there are no other error or warnings instead of the one above.

What else do I need to check, How can I investigate further what is wrong?

Comment: du you have multiple instances of the client application running?